# ASP.net Ajax.BeginForm for table rows

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, razor, ajax.beginform

I have a table in a partial view which contains a list of customers where each row of the table represents a customer. Now my aim is to wrap a form around each of the rows and upon clicking the row, it will populate a div with the customer details. However, as I am fairly new to using razor syntax, I am unsure on how to approach this. So far I have the following code:

```
<table class="customerResultsTable" border="1">
<thead class="customerResultsTableHead">
    <tr class="customerResultsTableRowHead">
        <td class="customerResultsTableCellHead">Company Name</td>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody class="customerResultsTableBody">
    @{
        foreach (EntityDTO customer in Model.entities)
        {
            using (Ajax.BeginForm("showCustomer", "VF", new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "customerView" }))
            {
                <tr id="@customer.InternalCode" class="customerResultsTableRow" onclick="submit">
                    <td class="customerResultsTableCell">@customer.Name</td>
                    <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.customerID, new { Value = customer.InternalCode })</td>
                </tr>
            }
        }
    }
</tbody>
</table>
<div id="customerView">

</div>
```

Obviously this won't work so I'm looking for guidance.

Thanks in advance

EDIT

Here is my latest attempt which does submit the form however, the partialView which my controller returns does not return it into the customerView div. I can only assume that this is because the document.forms.submit is not recognising that it should be and ajax call?

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("showCustomer", "VF", new { id="customerForm" }, new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "customerView" }))
{
    <table class="customerResultsTable" border="1">
        <thead class="customerResultsTableHead">
            <tr class="customerResultsTableRowHead">
                <td class="customerResultsTableCellHead">Company Name</td>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody class="customerResultsTableBody">
            @foreach (EntityDTO customer in Model.entities)
            {
                <tr class="customerResultsTableRow">
                    <td class="customerResultsTableCell"><div id="@customer.InternalCode" onclick="document.forms['customerForm'].submit(this.id)">@customer.Name</div></td>
                </tr>
            }
        </tbody>
    </table>
}
<div id="customerView">

</div>
```

Comment: I think this can be achieved by using a single form as well. You can use one form and loop all items in it and you can set modal popup on each link  through ajax. Also, what kind of div are you populating ? Are you using Javascript or posting the form back ?

Comment: So instead of having a form on each table row, use one form on the entire table and track which selection is made? Is this what you mean?

The div sits just below the table, the form should post the customerID to a controller where some data retrieval will be carried out. The data will then be posted back to a partial view which will sit inside of the customerView div. Hope this makes sense, @MattMurdock

Comment: Why do you even need a form? If you wanting to get some details based on a customer ID, then its a GET which you can do with `@Ajax.ActionLink()` or better, using the `jQuery.get()` method

Comment: You can do that or what @StephenMuecke suggested. With Ajax, it would be more smooth and that will be more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

Do you install Microsoft.jQuery.Unobtrusive.Ajax?
You should also add these:

In BudleConfig.cs

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryajax").Include(
        "~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax*"));
```

In _Layout.cshtml

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryajax")
```

Answer (score 0):

*Here is my latest attempt which does submit the form however, the partialView which my controller returns does not return it into the customerView div.*

First it is important https://stackoverflow.com/a/40839763/8092612
and after I think by adding InsertionMode it can works AjaxOptions:

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("showCustomer", "VF", new { id="customerForm" }, new AjaxOptions {InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace, UpdateTargetId = "customerView" }))
{
    <table class="customerResultsTable" border="1">
        <thead class="customerResultsTableHead">
            <tr class="customerResultsTableRowHead">
                <td class="customerResultsTableCellHead">Company Name</td>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody class="customerResultsTableBody">
            @foreach (EntityDTO customer in Model.entities)
            {
                <tr class="customerResultsTableRow">
                    <td class="customerResultsTableCell"><div id="@customer.InternalCode" onclick="document.forms['customerForm'].submit(this.id)">@customer.Name</div></td>
                </tr>
            }
        </tbody>
    </table>
}
<div id="customerView">
</div>
```